# Manually installing a newer version Mozilla in Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, firefox

I am quite new on linux so be patient please. After downloaded `mozilla` from its website, the file must be uncompressed. Actually it is on Desktop and when clicking on the executable it works.

**Question**

To make it executable as `firefox` from terminal I am not sure if:
An alias must be defined or the executable must be saved on a particular directory (I didn't downloaded it from synaptic because it is outdated).

I have searched on the web but didn't find anything clear enough.

Any help?

**EDIT**

Path:

```
cd /home/alumno/firefox/
```

Then if I list here:

```
application.ini     gmp-clearkey        libnss3.so       minidump-analyzer
browser             gtk2                libnssckbi.so    omni.ja
chrome.manifest     icons               libnssdbm3.chk   pingsender
crashreporter       icudt59l.dat        libnssdbm3.so    platform.ini
crashreporter.ini   libfreeblpriv3.chk  libnssutil3.so   plugin-container
defaults            libfreeblpriv3.so   libplc4.so       plugin-container.sig
dependentlibs.list  liblgpllibs.so      libplds4.so      precomplete
dictionaries        libmozavcodec.so    libsmime3.so     removed-files
firefox             libmozavutil.so     libsoftokn3.chk  Throbber-small.gif
firefox-bin         libmozgtk.so        libsoftokn3.so   updater
firefox-bin.sig     libmozsandbox.so    libssl3.so       updater.ini
firefox.sig         libmozsqlite3.so    libxul.so        update-settings.ini
fonts               libnspr4.so         libxul.so.sig
```

(on the first column is the binary).

Comment: It would be best to use your distributions package management system to install software, esp. "universal" stuff like Firefox or Chrome/Chromium - this way, the package manager will keep it all up to date, paths for libraries and binaries will be correct, etc.

Comment: @ivanivan that's why I wrote that on my distribution mozilla is outdated and need the new one..

Comment: From a terminal, can you `cd` into the directory or `ls` the directory where the `firefox` binary is?  If so, can you add that information to the question so that a solution on what exactly to add to your PATH (and how to add it) to make `firefox` run from a terminal, please?

Comment: Yes I will @WEBjuju

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @Time4Tea debian jessie, if I install from synaptic, I can't change language to english, not sure why.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to Debian Stretch, which would probably include a more up-to-date version of Firefox? It's not really recommended to go 'behind the back' of your package manager like this. That might solve the language issue, but if not, you can always ask another question about that.

Comment: I can't because it is a version bases on Jessie called huayra. It has some problems to upgrade distribution. I have tried with no success. See my other post @Time4Tea , but I know you are right..(thanks)

Comment: Ok, so it's not actually Debian, but a distro based on it. Why are you using Huayra, if you don't mind me asking? I'm just not sure if a relatively obscure distro like that is the best choice for someone who is new to Linux (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Following suit with [this answer from another community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix#answer-14638025)...but tailoring it per your specific need:

> You need to add [something like this] to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file [or ~/.bash_profile].

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/alumno/firefox/
```

If there is already a PATH export, you just need to postpend **`:/home/alumno/firefox/`** like this:

```
export PATH=[...existing PATH additions]:/home/alumno/firefox/
```

Don't forget to restart your terminal and/or source that file you have the export statement in.

Comment: Thanks. Should it work the same as installing from synaptic?

Comment: A package manager should be set to install package binaries (or their symlinks) to a directory that is commonly already in the PATH.  [As i mentioned, this solution from another community is a great read and also talks about symlinks from `/usr/bin` which will already be in your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix#answer-14638025).

Comment: The first solution works but not at all. I will try the second, what means the text between brackets?

Comment: you have to restart your terminal or `source` the file you put the export in.  my brackets were to explain that i don't know what your existing export is set to...do you have an existing PATH export?

Comment: i'm sure it can, but it's a hidden file, so configure your editor to see hidden files.

Comment: The problem with your first solution is that, when I initiate jupyter-notebook it starts on in the file where firefox is! I don't know why it is so..and suppose is related to the path

Comment: can you paste here your export statement please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /home/alumno/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox 
firefox
```